# open Openoffice calc using system command using python

Tags: python, openoffice.org

I am trying to open calc openoffice in listening mode using python.
Earlier i was opening it by typing following command in terminal:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice" -calc "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"&
```

Now it won't open if I use `os.system(command)` as follows:

```
os.system('"C:\Program Files\OpenOffice 4\program\soffice" -calc "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"&')
```

I also tried:

```
os.system('C:\\"Program Files"\\"OpenOffice 4"\\program\\soffice -calc "-accept=socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"&')
```

this results in following error:

> The program cannot be started.A general error occurred  while accessing your central configuration.

but while running this command from terminal  it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system are you using?

Nevertheless, I normally avoid `os.system` calls and prefer `subprocess`. Here is the link to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html).

As an example:

```
subprocess.check_call(["C:\path\program", "argument1", "argument2"])
```

This works on my machine.

Comment: Now it is showing "WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied".I am using Windows 7 32-bit.

Comment: Did you try to run the cmd as Administrator? On Linux I would suggest running it as sudo

Comment: Yes I am running cmd as Administrator.